# Express Session is not working with my localhost React Native App but work fine with Postmon

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, express, react-redux

The problem is that when i login from postman all routes work correctly and express-session also working but when i login from my expo react native app it show cors error.
i also use axios.defaults.withCredential = true but not work.
Please give me solution if possible

> OUTPUT

**Postman**

[here login successfull](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CF2jk.png)

[Here assignment route also work correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ts20.png)

**React Native App**

[Here when i make http request from react-native app it show this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsQsZ.png)

> CODE

Expo React Native app:

**config.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';
const URL = [
  'http://localhost:5000/lms',
  'https://lms-assignments-tracker.herokuapp.com/lms',
];
axios.defaults.baseURL = URL[0];
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
export default axios;
```

Redux code work perfectly

**userAction.js**

```
import {
  GET_ASSIGNMENT_RECORD,
} from './types';

export const getAssignment = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: LOADING_ASSIGNMENT,
  });

  axios
    .get('crawler/assignment')
    .then((data) => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ASSIGNMENT_RECORD,
        payload: data.data,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      if (err.response) {
        // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
        // that falls out of the range of 2xx
        console.log(err.response.data);
        console.log(err.response.status);
        console.log(err.response.headers);
      } else if (err.request) {
        // The request was made but no response was received
        // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance of
        // http.ClientRequest in node.js
        console.log(err.request);
      } else {
        // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
        console.log('Error', err.message);
      }
      console.log(err.config);
    });
};
```

Screen Component Where i dispatch my action
**Home.js**

```
import {getAssignment} from '../redux/action/dataAction';

class Home extends Component { 

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props.getAssignment();
  }

 //...
}

/**
* Redux Action
** /

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return bindActionCreators(
    {
      logout,
      auth,
      getAssignment,
    },
    dispatch,
  );
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

Node.js Code
**index.js**

```
//all imports are ok imports
const app = require('express')();
const session = require('express-session')
const cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors());
app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'Bukc AK',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,

    cookie: {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60, // (1000 -> msec * 60 -> sec * 60 -> min * 24 -> hrs * 1 -> days)
    },
  }),
)


app.get('/lms/crawler/assignment',auth, (req,res) => {
   ...
}
```

**login route**
this route work perfectly give response { loginSuccess: true, userId: ... }

```
app.post('/lms/users/login',(req,res) => {
   ...


   user.generateToken((err, user) => {
        if (err) return res.status(400).send(err)

        //here i set session.w_auth 

        req.session.w_auth = user.token
        res.status(200).json({
          loginSuccess: true,
          userId: user._id,
        })
      })
}
```

here session.w_auth not get value
**auth.js**

```
let auth = (req, res, next) => {
  let token = req.session.w_auth;
  // here token result is undefined
  console.log(token)
  ....

    next()
  })
}
module.exports = { auth }
```

Comment: Which exact route is not working?  Please show both the client and server-side code for that route and clearly point that out in your question.

Comment: app.get('/lms/crawler/assignment', auth, (req,res) => { ... })

this route not working in case of react native app but when i test this route from postman it work fine

Comment: in above description under output heading error images are available

Comment: in client side userAction.js line 10 not give correct output

Comment: basically this is cors error as i use cors middelware in my server side index.js file

Comment: You have a CORs issue in the browser.  That works fine from Postman because Postman does not implement CORs protections like the browser does.  I cannot tell from your code exactly why you have to CORs issue.  It is probably something in the request that makes it not be a simple request and thus requires pre-flight on the server before the browser will allow it.  You can read about simple requests and pre-flight requests [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Comment: If I was debugging this, I would look in the network tab of the Chrome debugger and see exactly what the request looks like (all headers and data types) and determine if there is something there that is forcing it to be a pre-flighted request, not a simple request. You will then either have to change it to be a simple request or add pre-flight request approval to your server.

Comment: i use my own midelware to authenticate request in which i get token value from express session which give me undefined. This token is stored in session when user login.
basically it happen as first i login it start session but when i make request to  another route '/lms/crawler/assingnment' my session does have any value. while '/lms/crawler/assignment' route use auth midelware where token is required which is previously stored in session on login time

Comment: The session token not being available is likely a different issue and probably has to do with cookies from one request not being sent with some other request.  You could log the `req.session.id` is several places and see if it is different, indicating the session cookie was not sent with the request and a new, empty session was created.

Comment: At login time it generate this id `UmVa1lZDHM94qTbwJpK8DPnkpfeCo1wu` , but when i access another route it will regenerate sessionID `rEFJC3k4-2RFmmTfR--IbZhwhjiD-ptT`. How i can fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, it sounds like you have a problem with preserving or sending the cookie.  You can start by changing this:

```
axios.defaults.withCredential = true
```

to this:

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
```

to use the proper spelling for that property.

Comment: no it write mistakenly by me in stackoverflow but in code it is correctly written using intellisense

Comment: problem is that my session uninitialized after each request. And assigned new id after on each request

Comment: that's why my token is undefined which is stored in session